# Get CRM WRPC-Token for display images in Webressource

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

In my CRM HTML-Webresource, I got to display E-Mail activities with it's images (saved as attachments) as HTML. I take the description attribute for that.

As I realized, at least in CRM-Online, every attachment-image has a WRPC-Token that I need for the correct file path to load it.

How can I get the token? Most of the solutions that I found are either old or don't work for my circumstances.

Can I fetch the token out of the given HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't make sense to me,

Attachments are stored within a database behind a web service, they are not at a file path you can simply open.

WRPC-Token's are used in security, I'm not sure how it is relevant or could provide a file path.

I would suggest writing code to access the CRM web services, this will enable you to retrieve the attachment data. There is an example here [Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete an email attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328344.aspx).